# GET http://localhost:9000/model/data.json 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, npm, cytoscape.js

[That is my diretory path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnO9x.png)

I'm running npm server on http://localhost:9000/ to use cytoscape module. But my server can't find my json file. What's wrong with my code?

my index.js file source code.

```
import './favicon.ico';
import '../model/data.json';



fetch('../model/data.json', { mode: 'no-cors' })
    .then(function (res) {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

my webpack.config.js file source code.

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/build")
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
  },
  mode: "none",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: "/node_modules",
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ]
};
```

I want my server to find data.json file...

Answer (score 0):

my terminal throwed me ERROR code...

C:\Users\user\Desktop\npm_test\node_modules\webpack\lib\rules\UseEffectRulePlugin.js:160
throw ruleSetCompiler.error(
^

Error: Compiling RuleSet failed: Query arguments on 'loader' has been removed in favor of the 'options' property (at ruleSet[1].rules[3].loader: file-loader?name=[name].[ext])

my updated webpack.config.js.

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/build")
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
  },
  mode: "none",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: "/node_modules",
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,'css-loader']
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.json$/,
      //   type: "javascript/auto",
      //   loader: "file-loader",
      //   options: {
      //     name: "model/[name].[ext]"
      //   },
      //   include: [
      //     path.resolve(__dirname, "./model")
      //   ]
      // },
      {
        test:/\.ico$/,
        loader:"file-loader?name=[name].[ext]",
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: 'src/model', to: 'model' }],
    }),
  ]
};
```

I guess I have no talent...

Comment: Hello 김석범, is this an answer to your question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).